# C# save word document without prompt give 'document is opened elsewhere error'

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I have a windows form with Office Word inside it. I am opening word documents programmatically with code (_wd is of type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass - I am using VS 2012, .NET 4.5, Office 2007):

> ```
>  public void LoadComponent(string path)
>     {            
>         if (_wd.Documents.Count != 0) _wd.ActiveDocument.Close(); 
>         _wd.Documents.Add(ref path);
>     }
> ```

My problem comes when I want to save active document. I don't want save prompt to appear - here's what I've tried, and couldn't cancel the prompt dialog:

> > _wd.ActiveDocument.Saved = true;
> >     _wd.ActiveDocument.Save();

If I try with:

> _wd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(_filePath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
>                                             Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
>                                             Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
>                                             Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

I receive Exception: 'Word cannot save this file because it is already open elsewhere.' - but it is opened only inside my application, nowhere else. How to save Word document which is opened without save prompt dialog programmatically? Interesting thing is that even if I try to save the document by pressing 'save' button I got save prompt dialog -> like the document was not created before on disc. But, the document is opened from disc, only it is opened programmatically. If I open the document with Word and then press 'save' I never got save prompt dialog.

Comment: Well, it's possible.  How often do you create a *new* instance of _wd?  Just do it once to keep out of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I receive Exception: 'Word cannot save this file because it is already
>   open elsewhere.'

You should only receive this when your document is open in another instance of `Application`.

The following example works for me, and does not prompt:

```
var path = @"C:\Temp\temp.docx";

Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Documents documents = wordApp.Documents;
Word.Document doc = documents.Add(path);
doc.Range().Text = "Test Text";
doc.SaveAs2(path);
wordApp.Quit();
```

Check for stray instances of the *WINWORD.EXE* process in your task manager.  They can occur if an instance of `Application` is not properly close(programmatically).

One of these stray processes may be holding your `Document` open.

Comment: You are right - I've opened task manager and found there many WINWORD.EXE processes opened. I wasn't closing those processes when I was closing my application and they somehow held my documents. With only one WINWORD.EXE, I am saving without prompt and without 'document is opened elsewhere' warning.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are not the only one expiriencing it.
May be a bug in MSWORD .
As suggested [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-word/error-word-cannot-save-this-file-because-it-is/0d92212f-27f1-4f2d-8e6a-5efb77063763)

```
·         Click on start->run.
·         Type %appdata% and click ok.
·         Go to Microsoft->templates folder and delete Normal.dotm.
·         Restart word
```